# Side by side calendar

Tags: 2010, calendar

Is there any way in sharepoint 2010 to display multiple calendars side by side instead of overlaid, like you can in outlook?

Googling has gotten me nowhere, since everyone talks about showing sharepoint and personal calendars side by side in outlook, but I haven't found anything about doing it inside sharepoint.

If it's not natively possible, are there any free or paid third party web parts that do it?

I did a little mock up of what they want it to look like.  They also want color coding by category, not by person, hence the colors, but I can save that question for another day.

Edit:  Don't yet have enough rep on this site to post a picture - link here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZHI79.jpg

Comment: Do you mean putting two calendars web parts next to each other on the page?

Comment: I did think about that...but the problem is when you go to flip to the next day, it would only change it on one web part.  Ideally they should be able to click one button to change the day on all calendars, otherwise it'll get too confusing for them.

Comment: Ah, yes, that would require some additional coding.

Answer (score 1):

You'd need to have a web part page that has a web part zone that organizes content left to right (horizontally) instead of up and down (vertically).  This will allow you to add multiple calendar web parts onto the page side by side.

Answer (score 0):

Bamboo has a [calendar plus web part](http://store.bamboosolutions.com/pc-31-1-calendar-plus-web-part-release-12.aspx) that allows rollup with category coloring.  I am not affiliated with them.

For a free calendar category coloring solution check out one by Mike Smith.  He has a [technique to color code events](http://techtrainingnotes.blogspot.de/2010/06/sharepoint-2010-color-coded-calendars.html) just like in your image, but these events are from one calendar.

You could have the different groups share the one calendar using the free solution until you purchase the Bamboo one or roll your own.